# Why didn't Kratos teleport himself and Titans directly on top of Mount Olympus?

Tags: video-games, god-of-war

In the end of *God of War 2* video game, Kratos got the power to control time and space after he killed *Sisters of Fate*. And then, he used this power to teleport all Titans to his time at the bottom of Mount Olympus.

*God of War 3* video game starts with Kratos and Titans climbing the Mount Olympus, facing the resistance from the gods.

Kratos managed to climb to the top of Mount Olympus only in the end of the game when he kills Zeus. But, couldn't this be circumvent if Kratos had directly teleported on top of Mount Olympus? Why didn't Kratos teleport himself and Titans directly on top of Mount Olympus?

Comment: Because a character's powers usually reset at the start of each game

Comment: @Valorum Not in this case. God of War series is consistent across games.

Comment: In a word; dramatic effect.

Answer (score 3):

Because landing paratrooper-style directly in the enemy headquarters would be a failed strategic choice. In the plot of the game he gathers the attacking force and advances into the enemy lines, Mount Olympus.